# Profile Synchronization exception in FIM

Tags: profile-sync, ldap, fim

I get the following exception when performing user profile synchronization in FIM to import user profiles from Novell eDirectory to our SharePoint 2010 server.

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MetaverseExtension.MAManager.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MetaverseExtension.MAManager.GetMAManager()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MetaverseExtension.MVExtensionObject.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMVSynchronization.Provision(MVEntry
>   mventry)

Even though exception is thrown I can see the correct profiles attribute information in Import tab of Connector Space Object Properties, however the object doesn't appear in Metaverse search and the attributes don't get imported into SharePoint.. If I disable the projection rule on inetOrgPerson, the exception is not thrown anymore, but then the profiles don't get imported into Metaverse.

Comment: What version of eDirectory do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring the user profile service for Novell eDirectory is not exactly straightforward. The best guide (as usual) can be found on Spence Harbar's blog. He has an article dedicated to configuring this:

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010upsedir.aspx